# Get information about inodes via snmp for linux

Tags: snmp, inode, net-snmp, check-snmp

I want to check `inodes` via snmp for `linux` system, set up check. I could not find the correspondent MIB. Can any one help me to get information about `inodes` prozent ?

Answer (score 1):

which version of net-snmp you are using? you might have to upgrade your package. this MIB has inodes information:

http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt

```
dskPercentNode OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION  
    "Percentage of inodes used on disk"
    ::= { dskEntry 10 }
```

Comment: I use NET-SNMP version: 5.4.2.1. But i grep the hole list and a i can not find dskPercentNode!

Comment: that version is supposed to have it, but you could be using a buggy version. you might want to try to update it in your distribution first if you can.  in any event, even 5.4 is a bit old by now, as centos 6 already uses 5.5, and centos 7 has been out for a while.